# Print concat vars inside loop

Tags: awk, scripting, grep

I have a code like this:

```
cat input | while read p; do
lynx -dump "www.xyz.com/p?=$p" | grep -m 1 -A 1 "Hello" | awk -F: '{print $2}' >> output
done
```

Where the content looks like this:

```
[$p lines from input]      [wget]
1111111                    Hello: John
2222222                    Hi: Maria
3333333                    Hello: Linda
```

It works fine so far and it is printing this:

```
John
Linda
```

How can I change it to print both `$p` and `$2` var in `awk` (or another)? Like this:

```
1111111 John
3333333 Linda
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this:

```
cat input | while read p; do
  { echo -n "$p "; lynx -dump "www.xyz.com/p?=$p"; } | awk '$2~/Hello/{print $1" "$3}'
done
```

Before the first pipe, you can group the commands using [command grouping](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping) in the form `{ list; }`. The advantage is redirections may be applied to the entire command list. The redirected output looks then like this:

```
1111111 Hello: John
2222222 Hi: Maria
3333333 Hello: Linda
```

and `awk` searches for the string `Hello` in the second field `$2` and prints the first `$1` and the third field `$3`. The output looks then:

```
1111111 John
3333333 Linda
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$2~/Hello/` miss "Hi: Maria"? Nvmd, just saw the update.

Comment: @KM. Yes that's what the asker wants. In the question the asker uses `grep` for that, but I reduced it to `awk`.